# Retrieving a single record returns empty using lwc

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am trying to retrieve a single record field of an object with the following:

```
  import { LightningElement, api, track, wire} from 'lwc';
  import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';` 

const fields = [
 'Customer_System__c.Name',
 'Customer_System__c.System_Id__c'`

];

export default class CustomerSystemWebComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId; 
    @track name;
    @wire (getRecord,{ recordId: '$recordId', fields })
loadSystems ({ error, data }) {
    if(error) {
        // TODO: handle error
    } else if (data) {
        //get customer systems
        this.name = data.fields.Name.value;
        this.sysId = data.fields.System_Id__c.value;

    }
}
get systemId() {
    return (this.name) ? `${this.name} Customer System Name` : 'Name';
}    
    }
```

This code works for retrieving the name field it returns CS-01024 Customer System Name, but when I change it for

```
this.sysId
```

It does not display anything.

I tried this:

```
return ( (this.sysId)!==null ) ? `${this.sysId} Customer System Name` : `${this.name} Not Found`;
```

and it returns undefined Customer System Name.

What am I missing here, should it not work the same way?

Comment: `@wire (getRecord,{ recordId: '$recordId', fields })` should also be `@wire (getRecord,{ recordId: '$recordId', fields: fields })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property sysId is not declared, you should probably add it as a public or private property before trying to assign it a value as you are doing for the other properties.

Ex:

```
@api recordId; 
@track name;
sysId; //Private property
```

Comment: ahh, yes. I missed it!

Comment: can I pass systemId as a query parameter? Like this: `https://mysite/customer_system_api.php?token={token}&sys={systemId}&type=header`

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't the solution for your situation, but in my case, my problems was that I didn't mark the Apex class properties with @AuraEnabled.  Ended up seeing the records populated in the Apex debug logs, but on alert, saw this...[image: Empty objects on data array]